# Little help using XmlTextWriter on writing "xhtml:link" element of sitemap.xml

Tags: c#, xml, xmltextwriter

Hello I'm trying to write a string like :

```
 <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.example.com/de" />
```

using `XmlTextWriter` class

I've tried this piece of code:

`// Write Alternative links
    _writer.WriteStartElement("xhtml:link");
    _writer.WriteAttributeString("rel","alternate");
    _writer.WriteAttributeString("hreflang", "de");
    _writer.WriteAttributeString("href", "http://example.com/de");
    _writer.WriteEndElement();`

Which generates this error:
**Namespace prefix xhtml on link is not defined**

But I don't need any namespaces provided for `xhtml:link`

**Question: How to achieve the string that I need using XmlTextWriter?**

### Update 1: I have changed to LINQ to XML

But for now I have another problem... For the beginning I'll show the code:

```
    private readonly XNamespace nsXhtml = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
    private readonly XNamespace nsSitemap = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
    private readonly XNamespace nsXsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    private readonly XNamespace nsLocation = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd";

    public XDocument Generate()
    {
        var sitemap = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));

        var urlSet = new XElement(nsSitemap + "urlset",
            new XAttribute("xmlns", nsSitemap),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xhtml", nsXhtml),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", nsXsi),
            new XAttribute(nsXsi + "schemaLocation", nsLocation),
            from node in GenerateUrlNodes() // Provides a collection of "objects", actually it doesn't matter since we anyway convert them to XElement below...
            select WriteUrlLocation(node.Url,node.UpdateFrequency,node.LastModified));

        sitemap.Add(urlSet);

        return sitemap;
    }

    protected XElement WriteUrlLocation(string url, UpdateFrequency updateFrequency, DateTime lastUpdated)
    {
        var urlNode = new XElement(nsSitemap + "url",
            new XElement(nsSitemap + "loc", url),
            new XElement(nsSitemap + "changefreq", updateFrequency),
            new XElement(nsSitemap + "lastmod", lastUpdated)
            );

        var linkNode = new XElement(nsXhtml + "link",
            new XAttribute("rel", "alternate"),
            new XAttribute("hreflang", "de"),
            new XAttribute("href", "http://example.com/de"));

        urlNode.Add(linkNode);
        return urlNode;
    }
```

The problem is that When I inspect the Generated sitemap at Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Sitemap()
    {
        var sitemap = _sitemapGenerator.Generate().ToString();
        return Content(sitemap,"text/xml");
    }
```

The whole xml is not as expected and, the `<xhtml:link>` element is rendered with a non-empty closing tag (thus I don't know if this is a problem here) .. Look at the image please

[image]

### Update 2: Solved! Seems that the XML structure is valid but the browser is not displaying it right...

Comment: Do you absolutely *have* to use XmlTextWriter? Using something like LINQ to XML makes all kinds of things simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, because I already have some work done in this style... But If there won't be any solutions i'll take in account your advice.

Comment: Well there *are* solutions to this - it's just that the more you write in this painful style, the more work it'll be to move to LINQ to XML...

Comment: Agree :) Hm.. So if to switch to the new way of doing this, you advice to choose LINQ to XML ? Or there are another preferable options too?

Comment: I'd definitely use LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change to use a different overload of `XmlWriter.StartElement`. For example:

```
_writer.WriteStartElement("link", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
```

That assumes you've already got a prefix alias of `xhtml` for the namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`. I'd still recommend shifting to use LINQ to XML as soon as you can though... `XmlWriter` is great for cases where you really need to stream the data (e.g. when it's *huge*) but otherwise, LINQ to XML makes things a lot easier:

```
XNamespace xhtml = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
var element = new XElement(xhtml + "link",
     new XAttribute("rel", "alternate"),
     new XAttribute("hreflang", "de"),
     new XAttribute("href", "http://example.com/de"));
parent.Add(element);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think I'll move today all the code to LINQ to XML. It seems to be much easier!!

Comment: By the way, the statement that you suggested, generates : `<link xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://example.com/de" />` is it equivalent with `<xhtml:link>` ?

Comment: @Christian: Roughly - but if you have an ancestor element with`xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` then it should generate `<xhtml:link...>` automatically.

Comment: Hmm didn't know this :) Thanks! I'll explore it deeper

Comment: Jon, Need you help again! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you will use XML Writer and write this

```
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="www.yoursite.com" />
```

you can choose this code for .NET CORE 2.0:

```
foreach (SitemapNodeAlternate a in alternate)
{             
    MyWriter.WriteStartElement("xhtml", "link", null);
    MyWriter.WriteAttributeString("rel", "alternate");
    MyWriter.WriteAttributeString("href", a.href);
    MyWriter.WriteAttributeString("hreflang", a.hreflang);               
    MyWriter.WriteEndElement();
}
```